# Error handling when saving nested documents in mongoose with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, logic

I have two schemas, User and Replies. I referred replies in users. The problem is that I have to create a reply, and then push it to user array of replies. what if the reply is created, and the user is not found due to any problem!? the reply hangs in the air without being attached to any user. Is there any workaround this?

Reply Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const requestReplySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    answers: [
        {
            number: Number,
            title: String,
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RequestReply', requestReplySchema);
```

User Schema (simplified version):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocal = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    requestReplies: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'RequestReply'
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

NodeJS Code for this part:

```
let postReply = (req, res)=>{

    let replyAnswers = [];

    if(req.body.answers && (req.body.answers).length > 0){
        replyAnswers = req.body.answers;
    } else {
        return res.json({status: false, message: 'answers not properly formed'});
    }

    const newReply = {
        email: req.email,
        answers: replyAnswers,
    };

    RequestReply.create(newReply, (error, createdReply)=>{
        if(error || createdReply === null){
            return res.status(400).json({status: false, message: 'error getting data'})
        }

        User.findOne({email: req.email}, (error, foundUser)=>{
           if(error || foundUser === null){
               // what can I do here!? the request is saved, 
               // but the user is not found or and error happened
           }
        });
        return res.json({status: true})
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you considered deleting the RequestReply and returning an error to the client in the form of a 404?

Comment: is it possible to delete the request right here?

Comment: Yes it is. You could also find the user first before creating the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Reply cannot exists without a User, first of all you must find the user. If it doesn't exist, throw an error, if it exists, just create the Reply, then attach it to the user found.

```
User.findOne({email: req.email}, (error, foundUser)=>{
    if(error || foundUser === null){
        return res.status(400).json({status: false, message: 'user not found, or   whatever'})
    }
    RequestReply.create(newReply, (error, createdReply)=>{
        if(error || createdReply === null){
            return res.status(400).json({status: false, message: 'error getting data'})
        }
        // TODO Update user with the new reply  
    }
});
```

Anyway, with Mongoose you can use promises and get rid of those callbacks, nested sentences, I think it's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Replica Set, you can setup Transaction (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html). 
Othwerwise i will try to turn the logic: I will retrieve user, and then saving RequestReply. After RequestReply is created, i will update user with the _id of the object created.